# Use Bash with script text from stdin and options from command line

Tags: bash, sh

I want to use /bin/bash (possibly /bin/sh) with the option `-f` passed to, and handled by, the script.
Precisely,

```
while getopts f OPT
do
  case $OPT in
    "f" ) readonly FLG_F="TRUE" 
   esac
done

if [ $FLG_F ]; then
  rm -rf $KIBRARY_DIR
fi
```

and when these lines are in a file http://hoge.com/hoge.sh,

I can do this, for instance,

```
wget http://hoge.com/hoge.sh
/bin/bash hoge.sh -f
```

but not

```
/bin/bash -f hoge.sh
```

I know the reason  but I want to do like this,

```
wget -O - http://hoge.com/hoge.sh | /bin/bash
```

with -f option for hoge.sh not for /bin/bash

Are there any good ways to do this?

```
/bin/bash <(wget -O - http://hoge.com/hoge.sh) -f
```

worked. but this is only for bash users, right?

Comment: BTW, you've got some quoting bugs here -- try running your code through http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: Ohmy,.... thank you for everything..

Comment: Also, `-f` is not the only way to set `FLG_F`; the value can be inherited from the environment. Try `FLG_F=TRUE bash hoge.sh`. You'll want to clear the value of `FLG_F` at the top of your script before you check for the `-f` option.

Comment: Running a shell script directly from a 3rd party is a bad idea; download it, verify that it will do what you expect, *then* run it.

Comment: ...and certainly not over plain http; if you don't use SSL, you don't know it's *really* coming from where you think it is. It really ain't that hard to set up a mutating inline proxy -- heck, I was doing that as part of an April Fool joke almost 20 years ago. Trusting the people you're downloading code from not to have been hacked isn't wise either -- this is why robust software packaging systems (and DSCMs intended to be securable) have support for OpenPGP signatures.

Comment: OK I consider what you say, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using bash you can do

```
wget -O - http://hoge.com/hoge.sh | /bin/bash -s -- -f
```

as with `-s` commands are read from  the  standard input. This  option  allows the positional parameters to be set too.
It should work with other POSIX shells too.

Comment: It worked.  Thank you very much you also considered POSIX Im taking care of.. appreciate it..

Comment: This is a bad idea for different reasons; you don't know what you are getting from `hoge.com` before you execute it.